# Import a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app that uses a lot of fetch requests. The requests are working great, but I'm now trying to move all fetch requests into a single file and import them into my classes.

The problem: I have no idea how to do this properly. Basically, I can call the fetch method from my class, but I don't know how to use it based on success or failure. See example:

```
import stuff...
import { FetchRequest } from ...

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    ...
}

 _fetch() {
 FetchRequest();
 }

 _onSuccess() {
 alert('success!');
 }

 _onFailure() {
 alert('failure!');
 }

 render() {
   return <Button onPress={this._fetch} />
  }
}
```

The FetchRequest looks something like this:

```
import { Url } from ...

export const FetchRequest = function () {
    fetch(Url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson.status == 'success') {
                return 'success';
            }
            else {
                return 'failure';
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           alert('Error!');
  });
};
```

As you can see I can easily trigger alerts, and I can also return strings that I don't know how to use. Basically I want to call _onSuccess method if FetchRequest was successful or _onFailure method if FetchRequest was unsuccessful. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by sending the onSuccess and onFailure callbacks to the FetchRequest function.

Change the FetchRequest as follows:

```
import { Url } from ...

export const FetchRequest = function (_onSuccess, _onFailure) {
    fetch(Url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson.status == 'success') {
                _onSuccess(responseJson);
            }
            else {
                _onFailure(responseJson);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           alert('Error!');
  });
};
```

You can now use this as:

```
import stuff...
import { FetchRequest } from ...

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    ...
}

 _fetch() {
 FetchRequest(this._onSuccess, this._onFailure);
 }

 _onSuccess(responseJson) {
 // Do something with the response
 alert('success!');
 }

 _onFailure(responseJson) {
 // Show the failed result
 alert('failure!');
 }

 render() {
   return <Button onPress={this._fetch} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` `fetch()` from the function

```
export const FetchRequest = function () {
    return fetch(Url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (responseJson.status == 'success') {
                return 'success';
            }
            else {
                return 'failure';
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           alert('Error!');
  });
};
```

and chain `.then()` with `_onSuccess` and `_onFailure` passed as arguments

```
FetchRequest().then(this._onSuccess, this._onFailure);
```

Comment: How can I pass responseJson to _onSuccess or _onFailure methods in this manner?

Comment: `return responseJSON` from `.then()`